# Meaning of "match Greek with Greek"

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

From *[Christmas Storms and Sunshine](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28636/28636-h/28636-h.htm#cs)* by Elizabeth Gaskell (4th paragraph):

> Jenkins had his wife too. Wives were wanting to finish the
> completeness of the quarrel, which existed one memorable Christmas
> week, some dozen years ago, between the two neighbours, the two
> compositors. And with wives, it was a very pretty, a very complete
> quarrel. To make the opposing parties still more equal, still more
> well-matched, if the Hodgsons had a baby ("such a baby!—a poor, puny
> little thing"), Mrs. Jenkins had a cat ("such a cat! a great, nasty,
> miowling tom-cat, that was always stealing the milk put by for little
> Angel's supper"). And now, **having matched Greek with Greek**, I must
> proceed to the tug of war. It was the day before Christmas; such a
> cold east wind! such an inky sky! such a blue-black look in people's
> faces, as they were driven out more than usual, to complete their
> purchases for the next day's festival.

What does *having matched Greek with Greek* mean? Is this some quote or allusion? What is its origin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The allusion is to the proverb [*when Greek meets Greek, then comes the tug of war*](http://proverbhunter.com/when-greek-meets-greek-then-comes-the-tug-of-war/), which means that a battle-royal can be expected between two adversaries of equal strength and determination.

So far as I can tell from your snippet, the author means that having set up such an encounter, she is now going to see the results.